# Does using a balance board help with skateboarding balance? If not what can help?

Tags: training, skateboarding

I'm having a midlife crisis and want to start skateboarding! :)

I actually have to work so I can't take the skateboard out that often. I was thinking that there may be something that I can do in the house while watching TV that will help with my skateboarding.

I've seen balance boards where you stand on a board, the board sits on top of a cylinder and you essentially can rock left/right as the cylinder rolls underneath the board. 
[Here's a link to how to build your own.](http://luno2012.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-make-your-own-Indo-Board-balance-board)  There are other variations. Some actually look like a skateboard deck.

Will this help me develop balance on the skateboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single best thing you can do to get better at skateboarding is stop watching TV and go out and skate. It won't take you long to get the basics, but having played with various balance boards and decks I can confidently say that while they will improve your balance there is no substitute for just getting out and skating around, up and over kerbs, along streets etc.

If you want to do it, give up a couple of hours of TV a day and skate solidly. It will work.

I learnt at age 23, having never skated before, although I had snowboarded and surfed. What did it for me was using a board for my commute - after about 2 weeks I started feeling the movements correctly, and even began to dream about ollying!

Answer (score 3):

Try putting your skateboard on something that your wheels cant move on such as grass or cobbled ground (definitely avoid sand and dry dirt) and try a few ollies or try lifting your nose into the air and staying in a "manual" position keeping your shoulders in line with the board and also making sure you have the right width of board if your toes or heel are dangling really far off the board (if the balls of your feet aren't still on the board when your heel rests on the back side) you will require a wider board giving you much more stability and control. people often disregard or don't take these factors into consideration I myself have just bought a wider deck and I feel much more comfortable and I've been skating for 4 years now. Keeping your shoulders in line with board will make sure your board doesn't rotate in front or behind you.

In addition, using balance boards will only help you balance while standing still. You will have to brave the streets to learn how to balance when pushing as your centre of gravity is constantly moving. the best way I know to keep balanced while pushing is to never mongo (basically never push with your front foot. keep your strongest foot placed on the front bolts near the nose. this is because pushing with you front foot means that you take much longer to bring your foot back to rest on the front as opposed to on the back. this would allow a lot more room for stumbling and instability. Pushing with your back foot is much more reliable.)